# How to get "singular" values in WHERE clause from a string?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a variable `@text varchar` which has some values separated by a symbol, whatever I chose it to be. Ex:

```
declare @text varchar
set @text='John^Marry^Smith^Ane^Sue^'
```

I need to delete some data, but because it is a different server and database (a very long story), I must specify the in the WHERE clause, the values from my string, something like this:

```
Delete Employers where employer_name in ('John','Marry','Smith','Ane','Sue')
```

Can this be done? Most of all without any other objects, like procedures or functions?

Best regards, Bogdan

Comment: as far as I am aware, any function or stored procedure can be inlined into any other SQL object. If this needs to be part of a single SQL statement, then that might not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way: generate your SQL query as a string, using `replace` to form your `in` list, then execute it.

```
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)
set @sqlquery = 'Delete Employers where employer_name in (''' + replace(@text, '^', ''',''') + ''')'
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery
```

Comment: whilst simple, this could run into problems if there are commas in the string.

Comment: @Tim Rogers: Sorry but the result in is "
Could not find stored procedure 'Delete from Employers where employer_name in ('john','Marry','Sue',etc)'.

Comment: @Tim Rogers: it shows now Incorrect syntax near 'sp_executesql'.

Comment: @BogdanM Sorry, you might need EXEC as well!

Answer (score 1):

IF I understand your question correctly, then the answer is yes, just at you have stated it. You can use the following strip to turn a string into a table. If you declare the return table as a table variable, then you can roll it into your script as a

```
DELETE where EXISTS(....)



Create function [dbo].[atf_BarListToTable]
    (@list ntext)
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (ListPosn int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                          SString  VARCHAR(1028) NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos int
    DECLARE @textpos int
    DECLARE @ChunkLength smallint
    DECLARE @str nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @tmpstr nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @leftover nvarchar(4000)
    SET @textpos = 1
    SET @leftover = ''
    WHILE @textpos <= datalength(@list) / 2
    BEGIN
        SET @ChunkLength = 4000 - datalength(@leftover) / 2
        SET @tmpstr = ltrim(@leftover + substring(@list, @textpos, @ChunkLength))
        SET @textpos = @textpos + @ChunkLength
        SET @pos = charindex('|', @tmpstr)
        WHILE @pos > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @str = substring(@tmpstr, 1, @pos - 1)
                INSERT @tbl (SString) VALUES( @str)
                SET @tmpstr = ltrim(substring(@tmpstr, @pos + 1, len(@tmpstr)))
                SET @pos = charindex('|', @tmpstr)
            END
        SET @leftover = @tmpstr
    END
    IF ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)) <> ''
        INSERT @tbl (SString) VALUES(@leftover)
    RETURN
END
```